# Entity Framework: Where to put business logic that that ASP.NET ModelState is populated?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-4

I have a site that uses Entity Framework for data persistence.
I have used the buddy class system on a number of Entities to flag what fields are required using data annotations.
ASP.NET MVC and its ModelState work great with this out of the box.
My question is, I have some validation that is a little more involved - 
Is there a way I can include this business logic in the buddy class in such a way that the ModelState is populated correctly?

An example of this would be
If field X is of one value, then Field Y is required.

The logic may get more complex than this.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should make the entities themselves implement `IValidatableObject`, then use an iterator to `yield return` a `ValidationResult` for each error.

Alternatively, you can make a custom class-level `ValidationAttribute` and apply it to the buddy class.

Comment: Went the IValidatableObject route and it works a charm - thanks

Answer (score 4):

This could be achieved by writing [custom validator attributes](http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/the-complete-guide-to-validation-in-asp.net-mvc-3-part-2). But personally I prefer the [FluentValidation.NET](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/) framework instead of data annotations as it provides a more concise and easier way to express custom validation logic even in complex scenarios.

Comment: Fluent Validation does look great and is probably something I will use on my next project